# GRID template syntac

Tags: templates, grid, syntax

having some problems with a GRID field type in my templates. I have an entrie setup with the grid field type containing three records.

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
    {body_image}
        COUNT1 | {body_image:count}
        COUNT2 | {count}
        FILE1 | {body_image:file}
        FILE2 | {file}
    {/body_image}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

As expected the {count} outputs 1 since this is the channel:entries count.
The weird thing is i'd expect the {body_image:count} would output 1,2 and 3. But it's output is empty. This is also the case for {body_image:file}. The {file} tag does output the link to the images I added.

Could someone explain this since this is the exact syntax used in the documentation?

Comment: Can you paste your code and then the template output?

Answer (score 1):

Might help to check if your really using the GRID field_type and not the MATRIX by accident.

Stupid mistake, but it solved my issue.